# .htaccess redirect just base URL while still redirecting all other internal content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

this is a bit of a pickle, and a pickle I wouldn't be in if I hadn't inhereted some one elses problem unfortunately.

At my company, we have a summer business and a winter business. Instead of setting up both businesses in the same CMS with similiar content, a previous contractor installed the winter website in the base public_html folder, and the summer website in a subdirectory.

This creates problems when summer comes, as people visit our website and still see the winter website, despite us wanting them to go to summer. We also don't want to make the winter website inaccessible by directing everyone from root into /summer/ and getting rid of /winter. We also have some SEO strength we've earned there...

**My Theorized Solution is as follows:**

1- Move all of the winter website into /winter/ (alter these are getting combined and built into a drupal CMS, so forgive the proliferation of subdirectories)

2- Redirect all internal content as follows to keep SEO rankings for the pages we have as best as we can and not confused visitors:

```
#redirect internal to winter page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?
RewriteRule (.*) /winter/$1 [R=301]
```

That code does infact work.

3- Redirect ONLY the landing page (http://www.website.com/) to the internal summer page /summer/

I was able to accomplish the first two no problem. The problem is with the third. I could really use some help here! I've googled for hours, and I don't understand .htaccess well enough to even know how to ask the question. I've tried to find some basic tutorials but more often than not I just find short little snippets of how to accomplish a task and nothing on the task itself.

So, anybody? Bueller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based upon the information, Please use the followinf code in sequence:

```
#redirect internal to winter page
RewriteRule ^$ /summer [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?
RewriteRule (.*) /winter/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. This response worked. I believe the issue with the response from Ansari was in relationship to server root, not sure what caused it though...

Comment: Is there a way to make the initial page redirect masked, IE: They won't know they left for /summer/ directory, it will appear as if they are at www.skibowl.com for just that initial page?

Comment: Use NC flag if you dont wanna redirect but to show the content from /summer/ on root!

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the landing page:

```
RewriteRule ^$ summer/ [L]
```

Add /winter before every request that doesn't begin with "/summer":

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(summer|winter) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ winter/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Putting these two rules in order should do what you want to do.

Comment: That came pretty close but it resulted in issues where subsequent pages try and add the server path in as well.

Thank you very much for your help by the way.

Comment: Oh right that makes sense. I hadn't foreseen that - can you try now with the updated rule?